# powershell edit file write in the middle

Tags: powershell

I want to create a powershell script that will edit a config file (apache httpd.conf) and if I find

```
 #keyword
some data
 #keyword
```

the I replace the data between the #keyword else I add the #keywords with the data.

Can someone give me some help
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$fileName = "..\..\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf"
$found = $false
$contains = $false
$kw = "##xceed.localhost"
$text = "A
BBBB
C"
(Get-Content ( $fileName )) | 
    Foreach-Object{ 
            if($_ -match $kw)
            {
            if($found -eq $false)
            {
                $found=$true
            }else
            {
                $found=$false
            }

            if($found -eq $true)
            {
                $contains=$true
                        #Add Lines after the selected pattern
                $kw
                        $text 
            }       
            }
        if($found -ne $true)
        {
            $_
        }

    } | Set-Content( $fileName )

if($contains -eq $false)
{
$value=($kw+"`r`n"+$text+"`r`n"+$kw)
    Add-Content $fileName $value
}
```